What's the difference between `JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates` and all the other intermediates inside `JAVA_LIBRARIES`?
I've been trying to study permission mapping by replicating Natidroid which uses Soot to extract call graph from the JAR files of the compiled Android Framework. Natidroid loads almost all the compiled files inside aosp8.1/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES.
But the framework.jar replacement guide by FudanSELab says the framework is specifically in aosp8.1/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates/classes.jar. Does it mean the all the other intermediates in aosp8.1/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES are not part of the Android Framework?
